# Mysql view column stays text, despite using cast/convert to char

Tags: mysql, casting, varchar

something strange using Mysql (5.6.39)
I want to make a some text a varchar datatype in a view..
just examples (same happens if I use real data from real tables):

it works up to length of 512

```
CREATE
algorithm = UNDEFINED
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
view conversiontest2(field1) as
select cast('sometext' as char(512) charset utf8);
```

result:

```
MySQL [xx]> show columns from conversiontest2;
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| field1 | varchar(512) | NO   |     |         |       |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

if I use any value larger 512

```
> ALTER
-> algorithm = UNDEFINED
-> SQL SECURITY DEFINER
-> view conversiontest2(field1) as
-> select cast('sometext' as char(513) charset utf8)
-> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MySQL [xx]> show columns from conversiontest2;
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| field1 | text | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

what do I miss? 
same result (of course) using convert() instead of cast()..

Comment: Hmm The length of a CHAR column is fixed ... The length can be any value from 0 to 255 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html

Comment: how can char(512) work then?

Comment: Hence the Hmm..